# Calculating min/max of a multivariate function on a region

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization

[This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UX1uENJvuO0) shows an example of how to find the absolute maxima and minima of the function $f=xy+y^2$ at the region $\{(x,y):|x|\leq1,|y|\leq2\}$.

I understand why he set $f_x, f_y$ to $0$, checked the values of $f$ at the corners of his boundaries, and along the paths $x=\pm 1,y=\pm 2$, but what I don't understand is why is this enough to cover all the possible points, wouldn't you need to check for example, the diagonals of the rectangle (boundary region)?

Comment: Yes, in general one needs to check the boundary of the region, so here the sides of the rectangle.  But you say the video did. The interior of the diagonals is part of the interior and need not be checked.

Comment: What I meant is: why dont you need to check all the points inside the region?

Comment: Because the candidates in the interior have the property that the partials are equal to $0$, and you say the video solved the system $f_x=0$, $f_y=0$. The only candidate in the interior is $(0,0)$.

Comment: You are welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For "well-behaved" functions $f$ in a well-behaved region such as ours, the only candidates for maximumhood/minimumhood are (i) the point(s) in the interior where $f_x=0$ and $f_y=0$ and (ii) points on the boundary.

In our case, the only interior point, indeed the only point, where the partials both vanish is $(0,0)$. That's one candidate.

You report that in the video, the boundary of the rectangle was also examined. This is in principle easy, we just solve $4$ closely related one variable problems. For example, on the line $y=2$, we are looking at $2x+4$, which for $x$ between $-1$ and $1$ is biggest at $x=1$ and smallest at $x=-1$.

Once we have the full list of candidates, computing $f$ at each lets us determine the grand winner(s) and losers. No other points need be examined.